# How to redirect domain to subdomain

Tags: 301-redirect

Could you please guide me to permanent redirect my website https://example.com/ to new subdomain https://ww1.example.com/

I don't know how to do that. Please help

I'm using vestacp.

I will really appreciate your reply.

Comment: Do the two have separate document roots or are they served out of the same directory?

Comment: they both have different directories.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the .htaccess in this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://new.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server is Apache, you need to add 301 redirect to your. htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```